# How to create some macros

Tags: manipulate, programming, output-formatting

I have two question in one. In the following code, I want to manipulate a plot in a centered cell. It is fastiduous to try always to remember the way to act. Could I define some macro as in a standard editor to keep some line of code pre typed ?

```
CellPrint[
 ExpressionCell[
  Manipulate[
   Plot[{n^2, n^3}, {n, 0, 1}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-100, 300}}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"n", "Wh[n], Wc[n]"}, 
    PlotStyle -> {, Dashed, , Dashed}
   ],
   {{\[Xi], 1}, 0, 1, 0.0001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
   {{Kh, 3}, 0, 20, 0.0001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
   ControlPlacement -> Left
  ], 
 "Output", TextAlignment -> Center
 ]
]
```

Comment: The exemple is artificial because in my case the function I need to plot werre defined outside the notebook

Comment: As a possibility, you might create a StyleSheet where the Output cells are always centered. Would it be OK with you?

Comment: Sorry Alex I have not react to your suggestion. No I want only the graphics centered

Comment: That's absolutely no problem. The nice feature of Mma is that one is able to achieve his aim by several ways, and chooses the way according to a personal taste and fine peculiarities of his problem at hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `Style` as follows:

```
centerF = Style[#, TextAlignment -> Center] &;

centerF@Manipulate[Plot[{n^2, n^3}, {n, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"n", "Wh[n], Wc[n]"}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Dashed}], {{\[Xi], 1}, 0, 1, 0.0001, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{Kh, 3}, 0, 20, 0.0001, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might define a centering function to shorten your notations. On the basis of your code it will be

```
 center[x_] := 
  CellPrint[ExpressionCell[x, "Output", TextAlignment -> Center]];
```

Then your code will look like the following:

```
 Manipulate[
  Plot[{a*n^2, b*n^3}, {n, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-100, 300}}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"n", "Wh[n], Wc[n]"}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Dashed, , Dashed}], {{a, 1}, 0, 1, 0.0001, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 3}, 0, 20, 0.0001, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, ControlPlacement -> Top] // center
```

yielding this:

[image]

The drawback is that you will need to first evaluate the function `center`in the beginning of every session. The ways around that I see would be to either create a StyleSheet as I mentioned in the comment above, or to pack this function into a package and to define it such that it opens together with Mma.

Have fun!